# If I have a matrix with columns {1,0,0} and {0,1,0} and the map f: $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$ then what is the rank and nullity?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that the nullity is the rank(kernel(f)) and if the vectors are linearly independent in $\mathbb R^2$ as we have here then ker = 0 therefore nullity = 0. With the rank, I'm not so sure. I know that rank is dim(im(f)) so in this case the dim($\mathbb R^3$).

Comment: The image is two dimensional.

Comment: can you please expand?

Comment: The image is the column space is the span of the column vectors which in this case is $span\left\{\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right],\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right]\right\}$.  It should be clear that those two column vectors are linearly independent and therefore form a basis for the image.  As the basis for the image contains two vectors, the dimension of the image then is clearly two (*remember dimension of a vector space is the number of vectors needed to form a basis*).

Comment: Don’t confuse the dimension of the image with the dimension of its containing space.

Answer (score 0):

The image of $f$ is just the plane spanned by $e_1, e_2$, not all of $\mathbb{R}^3$, hence the dimension of the image is $2$. In general if you have a linear map from $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, then $\text{rank}(f) + \text{nullity}(f) = n$.

Comment: You also need to conclude that  $[1,0,0]$ and $[0,1,0]$ are not linearly dependent or the dimension could be 1 or even 0 instead of 2.

Comment: The OP has already concluded this in determining the dimension of the nullspace.